# Is there any central repository in Azure APIM to save keep definitions, policy etc.?

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-api-management

Does Azure API Managment provide a central repository to keep the definitions and refer them at runtime? I am looking for a central repo similar to Domain in Swagger.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking a question, please ensure that you include what you tried so far (in terms of reading resource).

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no store option in APIM